# How to delete element from JSON array of objects by ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have Given this JSON structure:

`[{"variant_name":"Size","variant_options":["S","M","L","a"]}]`

How would you delete an object from the array by key/value?
Let's say I wish to delete the element with variant_options = S, how to get this result:

`[{"variant_name":"Size","variant_options":["M","L","a"]}]`

I tried but did't get any result

Comment: `Given this JSON structure:` parse it first, then you're just dealing with an array with a single object in it - far simpler than dealing directly with a JSON **string**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//get json value from your input
let data = $('#your-input-id').val();

//convert array to json
var parsedTest = JSON.parse(data);

let res = parsedTest.map(val => ({val,
  variant_options: val.variant_options.filter(v_o => v_o !== "S")
}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="your-input-id" name="your-input-id" value='[{"variant_name":"Size","variant_options":["S","M","L","a"]}]'>
```

Comment: JQuery really should not be used for something as simple as this, it's so much bloat for so little

Answer (score 1):

To delete an item from an array in-place:

1. find its index with `Array::indexOf()`
2. remove it by the index with `Array::splice()`

```js
const products = [{"variant_name":"Size","variant_options":["S","M","L","a"]}, {"variant_name":"Size","variant_options":["S","M","L","a"]}];

const removeSize = (product, size) => {
  const idx = product.variant_options.indexOf(size);
  idx >= 0 && product.variant_options.splice(idx, 1);
};

products.forEach(p => removeSize(p, 'S'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
```